# jQuery $.extend[ing] a functions with parameters returning empty function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, extend

I got a `form`;

```
    <div id="mainDiv">
        <form>

        <input name="input1" />
        <input name="input2" />
        <input name="input3" />
        <input name="input4" />

    <button id="showForm">Show Form</button>    
    <button id="sendForm">Submit Form</button>    
        </form>
        </did>
```

And this is my `jQuery` plugin.

```
    (function(o){
    o.fn.validateInputs = function(options){

      var settings =  $.extend({

       submitButton:'',
       submitFunction : function(){

         return ""
        },options);

   $(settings.submitButton).on('click',function(){

//......run the FunctionOfChoiceHere!
//...I tried.
console.log(settings.submitFunction) // This logs an Empty Function
})
    }
    })(jQuery);
```

And the General `jQuery`:

```
    $('#showForm').on('click',function(){

$('#mainDiv').fadeIn()
    var form = $(this).closest('form');
    var formData =$(form).serialize();

    $('input',form).validateInputs({

    submitFunction :myFunctionOfChoice(formData),
    submitButton:'#submitForm'
    })

    })
```

Now the `myFunctionOfChoice`.

```
function myFunctionOfChoice(data){

console.log(data);
}
```

The Problem is, when Click on the `showForm` button, this automatically runs the `myFunctionOfChoice` and `logs` the data.... Which is *Exactly what i DO NOT Want*. What I'd request is that, the `console` should `log` only when I click on the `submitForm` button. How can I achieve that?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you are calling the function right away.

```
//this calls the myFunctionOfChoice directly
submitFunction :myFunctionOfChoice(formData)
```

Instead you should be passing the function reference:

```
submitFunction: myFunctionOfChoice
```

Now, when the submit button is clicked, you plugin should invoke the `submitFunction` passing the form's data.

You can do something like the following to pass the form's data to your function:

```
o.fn.validateInputs = function(options) {
    var $form = $(options.form),
        me = this;

    //...

    $(settings.submitButton).on('click',function() {
        //the this value inside the handler will be the input and data will get passed
        //along with the form as the second parameter
        settings.submitFunction.call(me, $form.serialize(), $form);
    });
```

Comment: How would you pass parameters?

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "passing the form's data"?... How's that gonna be done?... thanx

Comment: @UniversalGrasp I updated the answer accordingly. This approach is also better than what you were initially trying to achieve, since the form data could change between the time the form was shown and the submit button is pressed.

Comment: thax again, really appreciate. Please, If I understand: What is being represented by the `me` or `this`... is it the `form` as a whole or the `input` (s) (coz they inputs are what are supposed to be validate by the `validateInputs`)  or the settings.submitFunction? and what is the role of the `.call`... Please your explanation is worth a million cash... Thx again

Comment: @UniversalGrasp I'm sorry, I've corrected the example. I did not see you were calling the plugin on an `input`, not the `form`. Basically now, when initializing your plugin, you should also pass the form instance as an option to your plugin, this will allow the plugin to retrieve the form's data later and also pass the form instance to the handler function as a second parameter. Also, `call` allows to call a function and specify the `this` value so that inside the function, `this` points to the desired object.

Comment: This Perfectly makes sense. and it is much easier than what i had in mind.. JUST_ONE_MORE_Question: I noce you have [3] parameters in the function `settings.submitFunction.call(me, $form.serialize(), $form);` but in my case I only have `a single` one and that is the `second parameter` in your function the `$form.serialize()` is what am interested.... What would you advice me to do?... thax in advance!

Comment: Same Question! how to use a single parameter?

Comment: @ErickBest There's actually just 2 parameters, because the first parameter to the `call` function is the context object so it's not getting passed to the `submitFunction`. Basically `submitFunction.call(context_object, param1, param2, param3...)`. If you only need one, then just pass one.

Comment: @UniversalGrasp See my comment above.

Comment: Thanks alot it worked and now I hv learnt new stuffs with the .call thingi. Your help is highly appreciated Buddy!

Comment: @plalx... That's cool. I think I need more Javascript [HomeWorks].